# OOP vs procedural in run-time

Tags: oop, procedural-programming

I have very simple question I cant find answer anywhere on the internet.

So, my question is, in procedural programming, code is in code section, which goes into Read Only memory area. Variables are either on stack or heap.

But OOP says that object are created in memory. So, does it mean even functions are written into R/W memory area?

And, does Os have to have some inbuilt OOP programs support? For example if OS doesent allowed to read instruction outside Read only code section. Thanks.

Comment: It depends upon language -- and more so, the run-time for said language. The current CLR may create objects on the stack (value types in most cases, unless lifted). Neither OOP or "prodcedural" say anything inherent about using the "data section" -- but read-only memory is read-only in any case. The ending is so confused I'm not even sure how to respond. I think the problem is trying to munge 40 questions as one. Focus on a single thing at a time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Generally, both OOP and procedural programming are abstractions which exist only at the source-code level.  Once a program is compiled into executable machine-code, these abstractions cease to exist.  So whether or not a particular language is OOP or procedural has no bearing on what regions of memory it uses, or where instructions are placed during execution.

The OS itself usually doesn't know or care whether a particular executable was written in an OOP or procedural language.  It only cares that the executable uses binary op-codes compatible with its native instruction set, and that the executable has an ABI (binary interface) that it understands.

Comment: OK, but, does for example MS Windows allow you to jump to function which would be stored for example in .data area? After all system has no clue wheather it is some data or instructios. And, whats also interesting, why does even program code goes into read only section?

Comment: @B.Gen.Jack.O.Neill, that depends on the architecture.  The ability to execute code stored somewhere other than the code segment has historically been exploited by hackers.  For example, most stack-buffer overflow attacks are basically an attempt to execute shell code placed in a stack buffer.  For this reason, certain hardware architectures will trigger a fault if the instruction pointer ends up at an address outside the code segment of a process.

Comment: the reason for read only sections of code is to prevent malicious injection of code. the system has no more concept of what is data or a executable command than it knows that you like cheeseburgers or pizza, only what the ops are to execute next. This is why compilers can CREATE executables, for instance. I think you should read up on the von Neumann architecture, for instance.

Answer (score 3):

This is a good question.

Whereas as object constitutes *functions* and *data* as being placed in the same spot theoretically, most *implementations* split it. The way you do it, is that code is split out and stored into the RO segment. An object in the RW area then have a way to refer back to that code in the RO area. The coupling of code and data is only used conceptually by the human programmer and the type checker to ensure that you do not violate the rules and principles.

A Java/C#-like language will usually be made such that each object has a *tag* identifying the type of the object. The object itself is simply a struct containing all the fields laid out in a prespecified order. This tag can then be used to look up which function in the RO-area to call. The function in the RO-area is altered to take an extra parameter, called *this* or *self* through which the contents of said object can be reached. When the method needs to refer to fields, it knows the pre-specified order, so it can do that correclty. Note that there are some tricks needed to solve inheritance, but this is the crux of the idea.

A Python/Ruby-like language will usually make an object be a hash-table where a method is a pointer to the code in the RO-area (provided that the language is compiled and not run through a bytecode interpreter). Function calls are made by looking up the hash-table contents and following the code pointer. Fields are also looked up in the same hash table.

With those basics down, most implementations make tricks to avoid the part where a pointer is followed to find the function to call. They try to figure out and narrow down the possible call to a single function. Then they can replace the lookup with a direct call to the right function, a much faster solution.

the tl;dr version: The language *semantics* views fields and methods as part of an object. The *implementation* split them into RO and RW segments. As such no OS support is needed.

Answer (score 1):

OOP doesn't say this. I have no idea where you read it, if you add a quote that would help.

Objects **are** variables, so what you know about variables is correct for objects. In languages like C# (.net framework actually) objects can only be stored in heap, because they are so called reference types. In C++ they can live anywhere.

> But OOP says that object are created in memory. So, does it mean even functions are written into R/W memory area?

From this i concluded that you think that functions are objects. That is true in far not every OOP language. It is from functional languages where functions are first class objects. Functions are in majority of cases immutable and are placed in read only sections.

Common OSes like Windows, Linux and MacOsx are unaware of objects. This is purely program concept. .net framework and java vm provide layer of abstraction. They are execution environments that have build in object support.